# UncaughtExceptionHandler changes exception message

Tags: java, exception, uncaughtexceptionhandler

Small example:

```
 public class App {   
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         throw new RuntimeException("Test exception");
     }
 }
```

Prints following as expected:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Test exception
    at App.main(App.java:5)
```

Lets modify this program:

```
public class App {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
            @Override
            public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
                if (e instanceof RuntimeException) throw (RuntimeException)e;
            }
        });
        throw new RuntimeException("Test exception");
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "main"
```

**Question:**

Why message doesn't contain any information about where it occurs and there is no stack trace, message?

As for me exception message looks weird.

Comment: The `UncaughtExceptionHandler` is meant to *handle* uncaught exceptions not throwing exceptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Java API documentation says:

```
void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e)
```

> Method invoked when the given thread terminates due to the given uncaught exception.
>   *Any exception thrown by this method will be ignored by the Java Virtual Machine.*

So if you want the program to terminate on some exceptions and print their message/stacktrace you should do:

```
        @Override
        public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
            if (e instanceof RuntimeException) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
                 System.exit(1);
            } 
        }
```